# Convert python dictionary to a pandas dataframe, but this code won't let me.(NBA Data scaping)

Tags: python, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
def get_basketball_stats(link='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan'):
    michael_jordan_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan')
    kobe_bryant_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobe_Bryant')
    lebron_james_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeBron_James')
    stephen_curry_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Curry')
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    df = pd.DataFrame(michael_jordan_dict)
    #is this right?^^
    df.head()
```

I believe that I didn't create the dictionary right. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use https://www.wikidata.org to parse machine-readable contents. Parsing HTML is extremely brittle and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Define a Function
def get_basketball_stats(link='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan'): 
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') #we got the whole webpage code as HTML
    #You need to specify which element of HTML you need, our case we need table element
    #The table is in the class "wikitable sortable" 
    #Right click in the webpage and click inspect (TO view HTML code) then u can inspect specific element
    table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" }) 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    return(df[0])
#Use the Function by calling it: get_basketball_stats('url')
#Here we called the function and stored in the variable
michael_jordan_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan')
kobe_bryant_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobe_Bryant')
lebron_james_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeBron_James')
stephen_curry_dict=get_basketball_stats('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Curry')
stephen_curry_dict.head() #we called the variable
```

HTML (tags,class), Python defining function, Pandas

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering questions, it is generally helpful to provide a summary / description of your answer outside of the code. Please consider summing up your approach and what you changed in a sentence or two.